# Prometheus Startup query

Tags: prometheus

I'm new to Prometheus and im trying to install Prometheus in my RHEL 6 server.
I have installed the rpm for RHEL, post that I have filled up details in config file as below:

```
    global:
  scrape_interval:     5s
  evaluation_interval: 5s
scrape_configs:
- job_name: linux
target_groups:
        -targets: ['192.17.36.189:3306']
          labels:
            alias: db1
```

When I try to start prometheus, I get the following error:

```
INFO[0000] Starting prometheus (version=1.1.2, branch=master, revision=36fbdcc30fd13ad796381dc934742c559feeb1b5)  source=main.go:73
    INFO[0000] Build context (go=go1.6.3, user=root@a74d279a0d22, date=20160908-13:12:43)  source=main.go:74
    INFO[0000] Loading configuration file prometheus.yml     source=main.go:221
    ERRO[0000] Error loading config: couldn't load configuration (-config.file=prometheus.yml): yaml: line 6: found character that cannot start any token  source=main.go:126
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indentation is off, http://www.robustperception.io/configuring-prometheus-with-docker/ has an example of a minimal config that should get you going.

Comment: Thanks I'm able to start it but the localhost:9090 page is not opening.. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

`target_groups` is renamed to `static_configs`. Please use the latest Prometheus image with the following.

```
static_configs:
  - targets: ['192.17.36.189:3306']
```

The above worked for me.

Also, is the prometheus port 9090 exposed in the container/pod/service? https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/wiki/Default-port-allocations